# Automate securing of Linux services ? (cf. systemd-analyze security)

Tags: linux, systemd, security, services, utilities

When you run a command such as `systemd-analyze security` (or a program such as lynis which, for services, runs `systemd-analyze security`), you may get, like I do, a list of 'unsafe' or 'exposed' services. That happens even after having applied a security profile with Oscap (eg. CUSP).

I have searched for information as to how that can be improved and found for instance the following resources:

- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/systemd-secure-services
- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/mastering-systemd
- https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/systemd-service-hardening.html
- https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/systemd-service-strengthening

Basically, in order to secure services, it looks like as if you really need to know the services good enough and in the first link, it's stated that "*Adding security measures in any sort of automatic way is impossible.*"

Does it mean that there is no automated tool, even maybe to deploy a basic set of parameters that could be a first step forward? As these articles were written in 2020-21, hoping something may have come up :).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tools, and can't really answer the question with certainty. But I can take a punt at guessing what is meant by *"Adding security measures in any sort of automatic way is impossible."*.
If you e.g. look at something like the output of

```
systemd-analyze security sshd
```

you'll find that 71 of the 80 listed capabilities are deemed unsafe.

Assuming that someone has gone through all of those and ascertained their viability, placed them into a database and given you (via a tool) access to those for automation purposes - how would you know with certainty that their assertions are suitable for your needs without testing if things break?

For the above service I'd *hope* that the maintainers of your distribution understand the service well enough and only gave it capabilities that would be widely accepted as safe.

Comment: Sure, I think I am getting your point and this was a question that I was wondering about too : when Linux distributions are released, there is a massive work behing that and as you said, parameters have been gone through in that process to make the system ready to be used as soon as it is installed. If users may wish to add an extra bit of hardening to reduce the exposure to security risks  - that's what I am trying to do with tools such as openscap, lynis or there, systemd - the question is maybe how should we understand outputs such as "Unsafe" or "Exposed" in 'systemd-analyze security' ?